Theorem 2.47 in Folland; understanding reference to an earlier theorem
I'm reading a proof of the change of variables formula for a $C^1$ diffeomorphism $G:\Omega\subset\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$ in Folland's real analysis text, that is $$\int_{G(\Omega)}f(x)\,dx=\int_\Omega f\circ G(x)|\det D_xG|\,dx.$$Here $D_xG$ is the Jacobian matrix. There's a reference to an earlier theorem that I struggle with.
Here's an excerpt from the proof of the change of variables formula in Folland's book (Theorem 2.47, page 76, 2nd edition, 6th and later printings):

Let $W_K=\Omega\cap\{x:|x|<K\text{ and } |\det D_xG|<K\}$. If $E$ is a Borel subset of $W_K$, by Theorem 2.40 there is a decreasing sequence of open sets $U_j\subset W_{K+1}$ such that $E\subset \bigcap_1^\infty U_j$ and $m\left(\bigcap_1^\infty U_j\setminus E\right)=0$.

For reference, see Theorem 2.40 below. I don't understand how he is using Theorem 2.40 in the quoted passage. Which part of Theorem 2.40 is he using? Moreover, I don't understand the role of $W_K$ and in particular, why $U_j\subset W_{K+1}$? I'd be grateful if someone could help me understand this better.

$\textbf{2.40 Theorem.} \,\,$ Suppose $E \in \mathcal{L}^n$.

$a. \quad m(E) = \inf \{ m(U) : U \supset E, \, U \, \text{open} \} = \sup \{ m(K) : K \subset E, \, K \, \text{compact} \}$.

$b. \quad E = A_1 \cup N_1 = A_2 \setminus N_2$ where $A_1$ is an $F_\sigma$ set, $A_2$ is a $G_\delta$ set, and $\qquad m(N_1) = m(N_2) = 0$.

$c. \quad$ If $m(E) \lt \infty$, for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is a finite collection $\{ R_j \}_{1}^{N}$ of disjoint rectangles whose sides are intervals such that $m \left(E \triangle \bigcup_{1}^{N} R_j \right) \lt \epsilon$.


He is using outer regularity (the left part of 2.40 a.).

This more or less comes from the definition of the infimum. By
$$
m(E)=\inf\lbrace m(U): U\supset E, U \text{ open}\rbrace
$$
we can find a sequence $(U_j)_j$ of open sets $W_{K+1}\supseteq U_j\supseteq E$ such that
$$
m(E)=\lim_{j\to \infty} m(U_j).
$$
Since all the $U_j$ contain $E$ it is clear that $E\subseteq \bigcap_j U_j$. If we arrange for $U_1\supseteq U_2\supseteq\dots$ (it's clear that this is possible), then since $m(U_j)\leq m(B_{K+1}(0))<\infty$, we have
$$
m\left(\bigcap_j U_j\right)=\lim_{j\to \infty} m(U_j)=m(E)\implies m\left(\bigcap_j U_j\setminus E\right)=m\left(\bigcap_j U_j\right)-m(E)=0.
$$
